# How to run a Python file in xonsh?

Tags: python, xonsh

I would like to execute a Python file in xonsh, the same way as `%run` works in ipython. In particular, I would like all the global variables from the script to be available in xonsh after running the file. How to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the xonsh language is a strict superset of the Python language, you can just source it:

```
source myfile.py
```